# Why does hit.point reset to 0,0,0 within the same raycast?

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm super confused. I am making a 3D fishing minigame with Unity. When I raycast at a water plane, I move a lure object to the point the raycast hits the water, which hit.point should provide. I had this previously working a few weeks ago and checked today to find that hit.point resets to 0,0,0 midway through the coroutine.

```
IEnumerator handleFishing()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, myCam.transform.forward, out hit, gunRange, layermaskWater) && hit.transform.tag == "fishingWater")
    {
        print("You can fish");
        print(hit.point);
        print(hit.transform.gameObject);

        yield return StartCoroutine(playerScript.fishingStart());

        // throw lure into water
        float normalizedTime = 0;
        float height = 10f;
        gunRecoil.enabled = false;

        Vector3 startPosition = this.transform.position;
        Vector3 destination = hit.point;
        print(hit.point);
<<Code to move gun....>>
}
```

[Here is the resulting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppFpa.png)

Why does hit.point change partway through?

You can see that the first print at the start of the coroutine is a coordinate that I want the lure to end up at, but after the coroutine partway through, hit.point becomes 0,0,0, causing my lure to always end up somewhere off the map. The final print is 0,0,0 regardless if I print "hit.point" or "destination." Weirder still, printing hit.transform.gameObject after the coroutine will result in a null exception, so hit became null somewhere along the way.

The easy fix is to set "destination" at the start of the if statement, but I don't understand why hit changes in the first place. What's happening?

Comment: Is any other method in your code changing the field `hit`? I think it would probably work if you would rather use a local variable inside the routine `out var hit` and not use a class field

Comment: I do have other raycasts in other methods that use hit, but I was under the impression that wouldn't affect other hit values. Can you explain what you mean by using a local variable inside out hit?

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

As mentioned from your description and comment it sounds like you have a class field

```
private RaycastHit hit;
```

and use this in shared locations for all your raycasts.

Therefore while your Coroutine is waiting it might happen that any other method is doing a raycast which apparently fails and thereby overwrites the `hit` with the default values (therefore `hit.position = Vector3.zero;` and `hit.transform = null` etc).

---

#### Solution

As said don't use a class field at all! Remove the

```
private Rigidbody hit;
```

from your class and rather use local variables like

```
if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, myCam.transform.forward, out var hit, gunRange, layermaskWater) && hit.gameObject.CompareTag("fishingWater"))
```

which basically equals writing

```
Rigidbody hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, myCam.transform.forward, out hit, gunRange, layermaskWater) && hit.gameObject.CompareTag("fishingWater"))
```